# Divide 2d array into 8x8 blocks c#

Tags: c#, bitmap, crop

I have been surfing around the network, but couldn't find any good answer.
So I have this code, that should crop my image(it's always 512x512) into 4096 8x8 blocks.So far so good.

```
private List<int[,]> PictureDivide(Bitmap Image0)
{
    int[,] PartPic;
    List<int[,]> MacroBlocks = new List<int[,]>();
    HeightDivisions = Image0.Height / 8;
    WidthDivisions = Image0.Width / 8;           
    for (int a = 0; a < Image0.Height; a = a + 8)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b < Image0.Width; b = b + 8)
        {
            PartPic = new int[8, 8];
            for (int x = b, sx = 0; x < (b + 8); x++, sx++)
            {
                for (int y = a, sy = 0; y < (a + 8); y++, sy++)
                {
                    PartPic[sx, sy] = Image0.GetPixel(x, y).R;
                }

            }
            MacroBlocks.Add(PartPic);
        }
    }            
    return MacroBlocks;
}
```

But when I just redraw this image with no changes is broken, like I missed some pixels. Is something wrong with my code, or if you guys have any better soulution i'd be grateful for a tip.

EDIT: Added example: Before-After. Maybe in how I reconstruct the image is doing something horribly wrong?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why are you only storing the `R` component of the pixel?

Comment: I used YCbCr, to get grey picture. so since all the values are the same it doesnt matter.

Comment: Can you post a "before vs after" example? I cannot see anything obvious.

Comment: And are you sure the problem is in this method? May it be in the showing method instead?

Comment: Added before-after. Its like, im missing half the pixels somehow...

Comment: Looks like inverted `x` and `y` Try this: `PartPic[sy, sx] = Image0.GetPixel(x, y).R;`

Comment: @AntonGorbunov Yep it was inverted. Thank you so much..Wouldnt have seen this in a year..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like inverted x and y Try this: PartPic[sy, sx] = Image0.GetPixel(x, y).R;

*answer for question closing*